# Override onclick event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one problem. Actually I have this structure: [`jsfiddle link`](https://jsfiddle.net/e7bm4mcf/)

When I click on `"Link example 2 with accordion"` it does expand the ul.
 But when I click on any link inside this, it becomes hidden because links under 
`"Link example 2 with accordion"` are inside `<li class="accordion">`.

My question is: How can I stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Add a class to child

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link example 1</a> </li>
    <li class="accordion">
        <a href="#">Link example 2 with accordion</a>
        <ul class="child" style="display: none;">
            <li><a href="#">Link inside accordion 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link inside accordion 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Smth</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Script

```
$(".child").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use event.stopPropagation() on the child elements. You don't even need a class

```
$("li > ul").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Nillervision/0gzx9Lv8/#base

Answer (score 0):

Attach the click handler to anchor tag instead of just accordion. Something like this

```
$(".accordion a").click(function (e) {
    var closestLi = $(this).closest('li');
    if (closestLi.hasClass('active')) {
        closestLi.children('ul').slideUp();
        closestLi.removeClass('active');
    } else {
        closestLi.children('ul').slideDown();
        closestLi.addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Here is a demo **https://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/e7bm4mcf/2/**

Answer (score 0):

You could make your code check if you're actually clicking the li element. If not we do nothing in the click handler.

I think this is the cleanest solution:

```js
        $( ".accordion").click(function(e) {
            // Check if the parent of the target is the same as the .accordion we bound the event to
            if (e.target.parentElement !== this) return;
            
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
                $(this).children('ul').slideUp();
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            }else{
                $(this).children('ul').slideDown();
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
                       <li><a href="#">Link example 1</a> </li>
                       <li class="accordion">
                           <a href="#">Link example 2 with accordion</a>
                           <ul style="display: none;">
                               <li><a href="#">Link inside accordion 2</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">Link inside accordion 3</a></li>
                           </ul>
                       </li>
                       <li><a href="#">Smth</a> </li>
                   </ul>
```